# jsPDF doesn't render div correctly ( text outside columns ) and size big and each div spreaded on more than 1 page

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

i have a loop that result in divs/tables , each containing 2 tables with user information,that are all inside 1 parent div.
When i use jsPDF to convert the parent div to pdf, i'm getting gigantic result where texts are being outside column margins and each table is spreaded on 1-2 page, the result in the following :

[image]

this is my first table, the other is bigger and gets seperated by half each on a page :

[image]

My script :

```
    <script>

var doc = new jsPDF();

    var specialElementHandlers = {
      'editor': function(element, renderer){
       return true;
    }

    };


    $('#cmd0').click(function(){

           doc.fromHTML($('#totalPayslips').get(0), 5, 5, {
            'width': 200,
            'margin': 1,
            'pagesplit': true,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
         });
      doc.save("Test.pdf");
    });
    </script>
```

My html :

```
  ?> <div id="totalPayslips"> <?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultGetPayrollInfo)) {
$net=$row['basic_salary']-$row['salaryTax']-$row['nssfTax']+$row['familyAllowance']+$row['transportation']+$row['school_Allowance'];


?>



<div id="EmployeeInfo" style="margin-top:30px;">
   <table style="width:50%" id="a0" >
     <tbody>
    <tr><td style="font-weight: bold;">Name</td><td><?php echo "".$row['firstName']."  " .$row['middleName']."  ".$row['lastName'].""?></td>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Date</td><td><?php echo "".$row['payroll_Date'].""?></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="font-weight: bold;">Employee No.</td><td><?php echo "".$row['user_Id'].""?></td>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">Receipt#:</td><td><?php echo "".$row['payroll_Id'].""?></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="font-weight: bold;">Branch</td><td><?php echo "".$row['location_Name'].""?></td>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;">NSSF No.</td><td><?php echo "".$row['nssf'].""?></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>


</div>
<hr style="border: 1px solid #e1dede;">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" id="aa0" style="width:50%; margin-top:30px;">
<tr><thead><th>Description</th><th>Amount</th></thead></tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Basic Salary</td><td><?php echo "".number_format($row['basic_salary']).""?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Transportation</td><td><?php echo "".number_format($row['transportation']).""?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Family Allowance</td><td><?php echo "".number_format($row['familyAllowance']).""?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>School/ University Allowance(Annuel)</td><td><?php echo "".number_format($row['school_Allowance']).""?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Income Tax</td><td><?php echo "".number_format($row['salaryTax']).""?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Employee NSSF subscription</td><td><?php echo "".number_format($row['nssfTax']).""?></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td style="float:right;">SUBTOTAL </td><td><?php echo "".number_format($net).""?></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="float:right;">Other </td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="float:right;">Total </td><td><?php echo "".number_format($net).""?></td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<hr style="border: 2px solid #e1dede;">
<?php } ?>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="cmd0"><i  class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>Generate PDF</button>
```

Not sure how to fix the problem, any tips please ?

Answer (score 0):

jspdf not working with css correctly you have to change the pdf

The one that i know is the **[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/home.php)**. It is great open-source solution for creating all sorts of PDF layouts

If you want very advanced features in PDF creation then try **[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/index.php)**. If you want just minimal features of PDF creation and want a smaller in size class then try **[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/home.php)**.